# How to preserve existing tags when re-deploying resource via ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template

I've noticed that each time we deploy our resource via ARM template this results in all tags that was set manually on these resource to be removed (more precicely - replaced to ones specified in ARM template). In this an expected behavior? Are there any easy way to preserve custom tags and not erase them? (non-easy way example is: read tags on resource before running ARM template and pass all these tags back to ARM).

ARM template mode is Incremental.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for automation to fix something you are doing manually.  If you want to preserve the tags, deploy them via template, not manually.

Comment: IT departament in large organization adds their custom tags to already existing resources (the ones created by our ARM templates). Every time we deploy a new version we just re-run ARM templates and they alter the resource, but it also clears the tags that were set by an external parties. I know that there are workarounds for this issue like "why external party sets tasg on your resource, your ARM templates must do this and noone else", but thisngs are how they are, and it would be very nice to have a seemless support for such a scenario from Azure/ARM.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes, this is an expected behaviour.
2. there is no easy way.
3. template mode doesnt matter.

you can try and retrieve object tag using `reference()` function and use `union()` function with the output object of the `reference()` function to construct proper tags, but I havent tried this.

Comment: "there is no easy way" - yet another gotcha with ARM templates deployment approach

Comment: well, i wouldnt necessary say that its something unexpected. they could make something like tagAdd property, that would just append tags, but this thing doesnt exist in ARM api (not template fault), so...